Disable a filter while using TestRestTemplate in Spring Boot integration test
I have some Filters annotated with @Component and @Order(1) that intercept every request and validate the token presented in the request. I'm writing a test for it using TestRestTemplate. I don't want to generate a fresh token and send it in the header. Is there a way I can disable filter whenever the TestRestTemplate fires up the request?

Do you have any endpoint structure, and what is TestRestTemplete ? is it a controller ? if you're using Spring security, also provide Security filter chain and access url to TestRestTemplete

TestRestTemplete  is this testing library provided by Spring - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate

Are you calling it from any controller (any endpoint), and are you Using Spring security, please provide config for both, the code you have provide is not enough to create any test case
